# Date format problem in exporting into excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, date, gridview

I am sending data to excel from asp.net website, in exported excel document. InsertDate format is `dd/mm/yyyy` and in most cases cell format is General not Date, so it is not compatible with my system date settings.

**I need to get cell format as Date** in excel so other co workers could filter it.

my windows date format is `M/dd/yyyy` while getting `dd/mm/yyyy` in excel from website.

example: if date is `24/01/2020` it is type `GENERAL` in excel, if it is `03/01/2020` it is type `DATE`.

Excel format pictures:

[image: Wrong Format][image: Correct Format]

here is sample code of sending data to excel:

```
var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grid.DataSource = userData;

BoundField column;
column = new BoundField();
column.DataField = "DocumentId";
column.HeaderText = "Document No.";
grid.Columns.Add(column);

column = new BoundField();
column.DataField = "InsertDate";
column.HeaderText = "Document Date";

grid.Columns.Add(column);
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");

Response.Charset = "";

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grid.AllowPaging = false;

grid.DataBind();
grid.RenderControl(hw);

Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

Response.Flush();

Response.End();
```

Comment: You aren't generating an Excel file at all. You're generating an HTML file and then serving it with a .XLS extension and MIME. That is a bad idea. Not all apps that can open Excel files will know what to do with this file. And those that do will complain that it may be corrupt. Instead, use a library such as [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) or [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to generate a valid Excel file. Assisting you with fixing your current code would be a waste of time, since you need to rewrite this completely anyways.

Comment: Yep, newer versions of Excel are going to throw a warning message each time you open this file which is not good UX.  Either use one of the libraries referenced, or you're going to need to loop through each GridViewRow and strip out just the text you need (i.e. creating a StringBuilder and each line is the row contents utilizing a separator like comma or tab).